# Understanding MAD Results

Tags: r, mad

I'm using R to calculate the median absolute deviation for a few distributions, but some of the values I'm calculating do not seem realistic at all.  I have the following distribution:

```
x <-   [1]     NA     NA     NA -0.003 -0.009  0.004 -0.001 -0.001 -0.003  0.001 -0.002  0.000 -0.003  0.000  0.006 -0.011 -0.003
 [18]  0.002 -0.007 -0.002  0.006 -0.005  0.000  0.008  0.001  0.009 -0.002  0.001  0.001  0.002  0.003     NA     NA  0.001
 [35]     NA  0.005 -0.002  0.003  0.016  0.007 -0.003 -0.017  0.000 -0.013  0.000  0.002  0.002  0.000     NA  0.000  0.000
 [52]  0.000  0.000  0.004 -0.001  0.000 -0.002 -0.003 -0.007 -0.001 -0.001  0.000 -0.002  0.001  0.003  0.000 -0.011 -0.002
 [69] -0.003  0.004 -0.007     NA -0.009  0.005 -0.001  0.001 -0.001  0.001 -0.001  0.006  0.002 -0.006  0.002 -0.002  0.004
 [86]  0.006  0.001  0.000  0.002 -0.002  0.007  0.004  0.003  0.004  0.005 -0.005  0.003 -0.003  0.002  0.004  0.003 -0.002
[103] -0.002  0.001  0.002  0.000  0.000  0.003 -0.001  0.004  0.001  0.001  0.005 -0.001     NA -0.005  0.000 -0.002 -0.004
[120]  0.004     NA  0.007  0.000  0.002  0.003 -0.006 -0.002  0.000 -0.002 -0.001 -0.001 -0.001 -0.006 -0.001 -0.001 -0.008
[137]  0.000  0.003  0.001  0.001 -0.001  0.000  0.011 -0.017     NA     NA     NA
```

Then I used the following code to generate my MAD value:

```
MADx <- mad(x, center = median(x, na.rm = TRUE), constant = (1/(quantile(x, probs=0.75, na.rm = TRUE, names = FALSE, type = 1))), na.rm = TRUE, low = FALSE, high = FALSE)
```

I get a value of 1 when doing this, which seems unrealistic because the values I have are much less than 1.

I used the quantile function to get the 75th quantile of the distribution.

Comment: "*I used the quantile function to get the 75th quantile of the distribution.*" -- why did you do that?

Comment: I did that because I was under the impression that it was needed in order to take into account the type of distribution

Comment: It depends on what you're using the MAD to do. Imagine your original values were in inches. If you use that constant, what are the units of your *something-times-* MAD measured in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By scaling MAD by the 75th percentile of the data, you've rescaled your MAD by what in some cases is another measure of spread of the same data.  Observe that if the dist'n is centered at 0, and is symmetric, the 75th percentile of the distribution is equal to 1/2 the interquartile range (the 75th percentile - the 25th percentile.)  (Actually all that's needed is that the 25th percentile and 75th percentiles are symmetric around 0.)  If the distribution is symmetric, the MAD of the distribution will also be equal to 1/2 the interquartile range.

In your case, the discreteness of the data means that you can come up with 1 for the ratio in finite samples without much difficulty...

You should put `constant=1` in if you want the pure, unadulterated MAD.

Comment: Could I then conclude that the scale factor is not entirely necessary?  From researching MAD, it looked as if the scale factor was necessary to take into account the distribution.  I have outliers in the distribution (this and others) that are causing the standard deviation to be larger than it should.  MAD without the scaling factor will give me a good estimation of the deviation?

Comment: Correct.  The point of the scaling factor is to make MAD an unbiased estimator of the population standard deviation (instead of an estimator of the population MAD).  For the Normal, the scaling factor is ~ 1.48.  For other distributions, it's some other constant.  But, regardless, unscaled MAD is an estimator in its own right.